# How do I set the "cover art" for my game?

Tags: xna, xbox

I thought this would be a very simple search but I guess I'm not using the correct terminology.

On the Xbox, every game in My Games has "cover art" (title art) that is displayed when you are browsing the library (This is usually the same artwork used for the physical case).

You see this artwork before actually launching the game and of course, most indie games have cover art as well. Right now, my cover art is just a grey panel.

So, how/where do I set the cover art for my XNA game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The box art is part of the game submission when you upload your game
>   here for play testing or peer review. See
>   http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/home/faq/xbox_live_indie_games#xboxfaq-submission
>   for details.
>
> There's nothing you can do to set the box art when you are just
>   testing the game. You can set a game thumbnail in the project
>   properties of the Xbox game project in Visual Studio but that won't
>   affect the grey background, just the icon next to your game and any
>   storage files it creates when you're browsing through your hard drive
>   in the storage settings from the Xbox dashboard.

I am pretty new to XNA but have found this information that you may find useful to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link! 
I thought it was something like that but just wanted to know for sure.